# how is memory allocated for local variables?

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, memory-management

```
int* pi;
{
    int ar[1000000];
    int a =3,b=4;
    ar[3]=a*b
    pi=ar;
}//ar is destroyed
int ar2[]={5,6,7,8,9};
char* f="zcxzsdaaaaaaaaa";
std::cout<<pi[3]<<std::endl;// prints 12
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I heard that the stack contains only pointers to data. And if so where is the data stored? For example `char* a="bbbb";` a - placed on stack, "bbbb" - somewhere else. Where?
2. Doesn't the above code working correctly mean a memory leak of 1000000 bytes? Variable `ar` is destroyed but the data that it pointed to still exists. And we can't use delete here since `ar` is not dynamically allocated.

Comment: I call upon the powers of UB to bring solace. (Really, **why is pi[3] valid/invalid?** The block clearly introduces a new *variable scope*, but does it say anything about the *data* or the *"stack"*? I don't see this part addressed well.)

Comment: (I would imagine that *in this case* the generated code "leaks" the data consumed by the array until the function -- as opposed to the block -- exists: (how) is this behavior defined?)

Comment: The reason 2. works correctly is because a computer never "deletes" contents of memory cells, it just forgets that it has anything of value stored there. So in this case you get the correct output just because you are lucky, the computer has not yet used that segment of RAM for other purposes, even though it is free to do so.

Comment: @pst - A function allocating the space for all its local variables at once can be an optimization. The language standard doesn't say how to do this. In this case, `ar2` and `f` are perhaps not allocated at all if they are not used. Otherwise they *might* have reused the space for `ar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I heard that stack contain only pointers to data

You heard wrong. The stack contains the actual data. However, if that data is a pointer then that is what is stored.

> And if so where is data stored? For example char* a="bbbb"; a - placed on stack, "bbbb" - somewhere else. Where?

Yes, `a` (the pointer) is stored on the stack. The actual string `"bbbb"` is stored in a fixed part of the executable.

> Doesnt code above working correctly mean memory leak of 1000000 bytes? Variable ar is destroyed but data that it pointed to still exists. And we cant use delete here since ar is not dynamically allocated.

No, there is a difference between arrays and pointers to arrays. `ar` (the whole 1000000 bytes) will be stored on the stack. This is different from `char const* ar = "... 1000000 chars ...";`. As `ar` is on the stack, it will be "freed" automatically.

```
char const* a = "abcde"; // a is on the stack, pointing to "abcde" somewhere else.
char const b[6] = "abcde"; // *all* of b is on the stack, all 6 bytes
```

The problem in your code is that `pi` is pointing to something on the stack which is no longer there. It may well be there when you run the code because "freeing" data on the stack doesn't do anything to the data in non-debug builds. It's not a memory leak, you just have an invalid pointer.

Final note: Although essentially all modern computer architectures make use of a call stack, the C++ standard makes no mention of it. Note that people will often say that a variable is "on the stack", but it may actually just live in a register. For example, if you compiled your code, the variable `pi` probably wouldn't ever touch the stack, it would likely just stay in a register for the duration of the function because going to the stack is relatively expensive (compared to registers).

Comment: FWIW the C++ standard does include a call stack (remember what happens when an exception is thrown). What it doesn't do is say how that stack looks like, nor does it say that data is allocated in it.

Answer (score 3):

`ar` is also located "on stack". You technically can access it because the memory is still mapped into address space (stack is usually mapped as a whole) and see the same data as previously stored because data happens to not have been *overwritten*.

Doing so is undefined behavior - you can read overwritten data or your program may crash or anything else may happen including perceived normal operation. Don't rely on this behavior and don't try this in real code (trying this for educational purposes and asking on SO is okay).

There's no memory leak here - stack memory is automatically reclaimed when the function exits.

Comment: In my understanding, you don't have any kind of strict guarantee that auto variables are allocated on the stack, although this is a de-facto standard that goes so far as coining the word "stack unwinding" happening during exception handling. But other than this, C++ does not require the compiler to use anything like a stack if I understand the spec correctly (a stack just happens to be perfectly suited). Still, for every _real_ compiler that I've ever seen, this answer is exactly what it's all about. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. you heard wrong. the stack contains the data
2. no, the whole array can be considered "destroyed" when it gets out of scope

Answer (score 0):

1) All variables are on the stack. You don't allocate memory yourself.

2) There is no memory leak. The whole variable is on the stack and is destroyed when the scope of the variable is exited. You're not allocating anything with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt seem the confusion of memory leakage is really addressed. In C++ to allocate memory yourself you use the **new** keyword or **malloc** and this is when memory leakage is a concern. The lanaguage is designed that all local variables memory space are reclaimed once it becomes out of scope. As everyone pointed the ar is in the local scope of pi{} so once that is exited, those memory locations could be reused or easily overwritten,so if you would have printed the results of pi later in the code with manipulating the stack like you were in that {} scope than pi could be a different value